# View incoming http requests using ETW

Tags: etw

I would like to monitor incoming http requests using ETW?

I`m having trouble finding a provider to subscribe to?

Keep in mind that I am noob with ETW.

Any documentation or ideas are welcome.

Thanks

### EDIT

Looking at the Microsoft-Windows-HttpService provider - what event would I suscribe to?

Comment: try **Microsoft-Windows-HttpService** with **xperf -start UserLogger -on Microsoft-Windows-HttpService:::'stack' -BufferSize 2048 -f User.etl**